# In Pandemic, at the end of your turn can you discard even when you have fewer than 7 cards, so the Archivist can pick up that card on his next turn?

Tags: pandemic-on-the-brink

In Pandemic, at the end of your turn can you discard a card even when you have fewer than 7 cards, so that the Archivist can pick up that card on his next turn?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, discarding is not one of your choices of actions, and the discarding to hand limit is very specifically only for when you have too many cards.

If you want to discard a specific card like this, your best available option is to use it for an action: fly to that city, fly from that city to anywhere, or build a research station.

Comment: I'm actually surprised by that answer, that you cannot discard any time except when you've exceeded 7 cards in your hand. But since that is the way it is, your tips for getting a certain card into the discard pile are helpful. We'll see if I remember the obvious next time. :) Thanks!

Comment: So, to paraphrase, the act of discarding is something done ONLY when you've exceeded 7 cards in your hand. Discarding is not an option at any other time.

Comment: It could be noted that in expansions there might be additional options for discard, including adding a discard action to player. But they are still explicitly stated.

Answer (score -1):

While @[Jefromi](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/409/jefromi)'s [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/28233/180) is correct, you *could* use an Event card (like Airlift) and not have it count against your action limit.

Whether or not that is *helpful* (especially when you can play them at any point, even not on your turn) is another question entirely.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question at all.  It isn't about action limits or getting under the hand limit, it is specifically about voluntarily discarding city cards.

Comment: @bwarner - the OP asked about whether you could discard a card with fewer than 7 in your hand. This is the closest you can get to that request.

Comment: Playing is different from discarding, and is useless for the Archivist scenario that is clearly the OP's focus.

Comment: @bwarner - hence my comment that is the closest you can get to what the OP asks for.

Answer (score -3):

I would beg to differ with Jefromi.  As per the On The Brink expansion instructions, if a player wants to discard a card voluntarily it will cost them an action.  This is explained on the back page under the Archivist section.

Comment: Could you include the actual quote from the rules?

Comment: This is not correct, that section clearly states you can only discard when over the limit or performing an action requiring you to discard a card. `Players may not freely discard cards (for the Archivist to retrieve);
they may discard only by doing an action requiring a discard or
when over their hand limits.`